# How can I reset my password with "reset password"?

Tags: macos, password

I cannot find my password. Tried to reset from terminal by typing reset password  I see the prompt, but it does not allow me to fill in any blanks

Comment: Please help us help you. What did you do to get to the `reset password` part (how did you reboot your Mac), what kind of output do you expect while entering  a new password?

Answer (score 2):

Typing `reset password` on the terminal will not reset the password.

`reset` is a command to initialise the terminal, and takes a terminal type as argument. Typing `reset password` will only generate an error:

```
$ reset password
reset: unknown terminal type password
Terminal type?
```

The command you are looking for is `resetpassword` (without space): see https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-4101

- boot in recovery mode (press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> during boot)
- open a terminal (Utilities, Terminal)
- type `resetpassword`